# Is GC.AddMemoryPressure appropriate when using Marshal.AllocHGlobal?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Does

```
IntPtr ip = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
```

implicitly add memory pressure (a la GC.AddMemoryPressure)?  True it's allocating unmanaged memory, but it doesn't do it "out of the sight of CLR."  I could see an argument for either adding or not adding.

It seems like it could (and perhaps should).  But I need to know what it actually *does*.

Comment: *"Does `IntPtr ip = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);`
implicitly add memory pressure (a la GC.AddMemoryPressure)?"* If i understand your question, the answer is no.  if it was implicit we wouldn't need it

Comment: @TheGeneral - I always assumed AddMemoryPressure was for things like `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` which returns an object of indeterminate size.  Similarly, any pointers or objects returned from `DllImport` functions would fall in the same boat (if they are kept around long enough to matter).  AllocHGlobal is different in that as a CLR function, it can add the memory pressure itself while `CreateInstance` and `DllImport` functions can't.

Comment: @mjwills - `Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(clsidTransform);`

Comment: Actually that's kind of backwards, `Activator.CreateInstance` is just a vanilla managed method that creates managed objects which may or may not create unmanaged memory. the garbage collector knows the types its is creating with it. the only thing it doesn't know is what you are doing with unmanaged memory and therefor cant provide an optimal service as a garbage collector. Hence why we have these methods `AddMemoryPressure`

Comment: `But I need to know what it actually does.` https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs,1177

Comment: Not if the object is a COM object.  While a COM object can be managed, it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs,1177) (or for [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/23918ce912fc051b4a2443977e6973e34988c4f4/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/Marshal.CoreCLR.cs#L253)), no it doesn't call `GC.AddMemoryPressure`.

Comment: FYI: I was using a wrapper for AllocHGlobal and FreeHGlobal, so adding the AddMemoryPressure was pretty easy (the size is right there).  Adding the RemoveMemoryPressure was a challenge since typically the Free call only gets the pointer, not the size.  Fortunately the allocator being used here has a function to turn the pointer into a size ([LocalSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localsize) from kernel32.dll).  While Marshal doesn't have a method for it, PInvoking it seems to work fine.